# Solving Linear Congruences $ax+c = b \pmod{m}$

Tags: number-theory

I am facing this problem i know how to solve $ax = b \pmod{m}$. For example
$16x = 52 \pmod{52}$: I know that the result is $0,13,26,39$ or $13k$ but what is the solution for $16x + 48 = 52 \pmod{52}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT : Notice that $16x + 48 = 16(x+3)$

Comment: so the result is -3, 10, 23, 36 ?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps you want to express $-3$ as $49$ but they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate congruences mostly like you do ordinary algebra, just take care when "dividing" and you run into numbers that aren't relatively prime. In your case:
\begin{align}
16 x + 48 &\equiv 52 \pmod{52} \\
16 x           &\equiv 4   \pmod{52}
\end{align}
Now the last one means there is a $c$ such that:
\begin{align}
16 x - 4 &=            52 c \\
4 x  - 1   &=           13 c\\
4 x           &\equiv 1 \pmod{13}
\end{align}
If you hadn't been able to simplify to relatively prime numbers, there would have been no solution.
Now, since $10 \cdot 4 = 3 \cdot 13 + 1$:
$$
x \equiv 10 \pmod{13}
$$

Comment: what i have done is $16(x+3)≡ 52 (mod 52)$ and then i say that $x' = (x+3)$ and $16x'≡ 52 (mod 52)$ i solve for x' where i find that the solutions are 0,13,26,39 and then x=x'-3 for each so the finale solution is -3, 10, 23, 36 is that correct? or is better to start from the begining and solve the $16x≡4(mod52)$

Comment: @nicolasmanic, that is the same thing

Comment: I agree with vonbrand. The method I proposed assumes you already know the solution to $16x \equiv 52 \mod 52$. His method is more general but both are perfectly valid.

Comment: @user88595, I wanted to show the general case

Comment: @vonbrand: Yes I agree. It is more important to understand the general case.